# Trying to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.4 on Debian

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, upgrade

After upgrading my Debian development box I have both PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.4 on my system.  I want to have 9.4 serve my data and get rid of the outdated version.

AFAICS, it is important to use a working directory where the `postgres` user can write, and configure the old and new services in a way which allows them to run simultaneously (using different ports).  Thus, this is what I tried:

```
# cd /tmp/
# sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_upgrade \
--check \
--retain \
--old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/ \
--new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/ \
--old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main \
--new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main \
--old-options /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf \
--new-options=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf \
--old-port=5433 \
--new-port=5432
```

This failed (because of postmasters serving the running services).

The `--old-port` and `--new-port` options mirror the settings in the configuration files; thus, both services are able to run at the same time.  I stopped them both and tried again:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

*failure*
Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_server.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.

connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?


could not connect to old postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main" -o "-p 5433 -b /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directory='/tmp'" start
Failure, exiting
```

The log file `pg_upgrade_server.log` contains:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  pg_upgrade run on Mon Jul 18 11:46:33 2016
-----------------------------------------------------------------

command: "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main" -o "-p 5433 -b /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directory='/tmp'" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
waiting for server to start....postgres: invalid argument: "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"
Try "postgres --help" for more information.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

As far as `pg_ctl --help` tells me, there is no `-b` option; the file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` does exist.

What is going on here, and how can I get the upgrade done?

Answer (score 1):

For the records, I gave up trying this method and did it via `pg_dumpall` instead.

Here is [my earlier question in the unix area](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296164/clean-up-conflicting-postgresql-installations) (with some more detail), and of course [the PostgreSQL docs about upgrading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html) where this is still the first method described (and obviously prefered).